# How to enable ng global object in devtools console?

Tags: angular

i would like to use the ng object in the devtools console in my browser,
so how can i enable it so i can debug and check component data?

For example i would like to target and check some component with ng.getComponent($0)
but at the moment when i run my application locally and if i try that in my chrome console i get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined
```

[image]

This is the angular version that im using but i dont know if it has to do something with it, i hope it wasnt removed with the newer versions of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install Angular DevTools extension in Chrome - very useful for this sort of debugging, and gives you the same (+ more advanced) `ng` commands in the `console`

- https://angular.io/guide/devtools

Comment: thanks for the comment up on my post, that pointed me in the right direction, i checked my angular script and i just switched the "optimization" property to false in my development configuration, now i have the ng property in my console, also the devtools extension wasnt working before i turned that property to false, i was getting an error that im still in production mode.